# getting errr while running nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i  am getting this error while running mongodb with nodemon

```
POST /api/user/createAccount 200 3.747 ms - 607
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\personal\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:805
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\personal\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:805:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\personal\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:780:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 4152731,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\personal\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:367:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\personal\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:290:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v18.17.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

this error occurs every after some time while running the api post call from postman and it refuses it
. can some one help me in solving this problem.
i have reactivated ipv6 again but it does not solve the problem so can any one help m in solving this.

Comment: this is error message i will get when i tried to know what error is this {   "Namespace must be array-like (16 iterable integer values, 0-255) }

Answer (score 0):

localhost:27017

here use : 127.0.0.1:27017 instead of localhost